# ChartJS v2 - Keep tooltip open when user click on a point of a multiple lines chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I use chartJS v2.

I try to keep tooltip open when user click on a point of a multiple lines chart. The tooltip must contains the data for each lines for one abscissa value.
I wrote a chartJS plugin to do it and it works but it displays only the data for one line.

**Here is the fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/bencarbon/jrpLh8pa/

Here is the plugin:

```
    var keepTooltipOpenPlugin = {

      beforeRender: function(chart) {

    // We are looking for bubble which owns "keepTooltipOpen" parameter.
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        chart.pluginTooltips = [];
        for (i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
            if (datasets[i].data[j].keepTooltipOpen && !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden) {
            //When we find one, we are pushing all informations to create the tooltip.
              chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                _chart: chart.chart,
                _chartInstance: chart,
                _data: chart.data,
                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                _active: [chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j]]
              }, chart));
            }
          }
        }
      }, // end beforeRender

      afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {

          // Draw tooltips
          Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
            tooltip.initialize();
            tooltip.update();
            tooltip.pivot();
            tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
          });


        } // end afterDatasetsDraw
    }

    Chart.pluginService.register(keepTooltipOpenPlugin);
```

I use it in this way:

```
function handleClick(evt) {
    var activeElement = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    if(activeElement.length>0){
        var values = myLineChart.data.datasets[activeElement[0]._datasetIndex].data[activeElement[0]._index];
        if(values.keepTooltipOpen)
            values.keepTooltipOpen = false;
        else
          values.keepTooltipOpen = true;
    }
};
```

**How should I modify my plugin to display the data for each lines in the tooltip??**

Thanks

Comment: This example shows a combined tooltip staying open after click. Is there any way to make the tooltip only have one line's data and be attached to that line only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is interesting, so I updated the jsfiddle. Let me know if you found a bug:

https://jsfiddle.net/bencarbon/jrpLh8pa/4/

Here is the new plugin:

```
var keepTooltipOpenPlugin = {

      beforeRender: function(chart) {

    // We are looking for bubble which owns "keepTooltipOpen" parameter.
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        chart.pluginTooltips = [];
    var abscissaToShow = chart.data.keepShowing;
    abscissaToShow.forEach(function(element) {
      var activeArray = [];
      for (i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
        if(!chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden)
                activeArray.push(chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[element])
      }
      chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                _chart: chart.chart,
                _chartInstance: chart,
                _data: chart.data,
                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                _active: activeArray
              }, chart));
    });
}, // end beforeRender

      afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {

          // Draw tooltips
          Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
            tooltip.initialize();
            tooltip.update();
            tooltip.pivot();
            tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
          });


        } // end afterDatasetsDraw
    }

    Chart.pluginService.register(keepTooltipOpenPlugin);
```

Comment: This example shows a combined tooltip staying open after click. Is there any way to make the tooltip only have one line's data and be attached to that line only?

Answer (score 0):

you could just use the events option:

```
chartOptions = {

            events: ["click", "mouseout"],

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 