# Chartjs - keep tooltip open when user clicks on a datapoint in chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843226/chartjs-v2-keep-tooltip-open-when-user-click-on-a-point-of-a-multiple-lines-ch/45885221#45885221) with the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarbon/jrpLh8pa/), which does exactly what I need. Seems like the answer is outdated, but I am not able to get it working.

What I am trying to create a plugin to that will allow the user to click on a datapoint on the chart, and the tooltip will stay open. Then click on another datapoint, and that tooltip will stay open aswell. This will allow the user to more easily compare data in two different tooltips. The "click" event would be useful if it allowed for multiple tooltips at the same time. Any ideas, or pointers to the right direction would be greatly apprieciated!

The following is the plugin from the other thread (creds to Marine Giraud)

```
var keepTooltipOpenPlugin = {

      beforeRender: function(chart) {
  
    // We are looking for bubble which owns "keepTooltipOpen" parameter.
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        chart.pluginTooltips = [];
        for (i = 0; i < datasets.length; i++) {
          for (j = 0; j < datasets[i].data.length; j++) {
            if (datasets[i].data[j].keepTooltipOpen && !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden) {
            //When we find one, we are pushing all informations to create the tooltip.
              chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                _chart: chart.chart,
                _chartInstance: chart,
                _data: chart.data,
                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                _active: [chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data[j]]
              }, chart));
            }
          }
        }
      }, // end beforeRender
  
      afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, easing) {

          // Draw tooltips
          Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
            tooltip.initialize();
            tooltip.update();
            tooltip.pivot();
            tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
          });


        } // end afterDatasetsDraw
    }
```

Comment: The "click" event would be useful if it allowed for multiple tooltips at the same time is achieved in the fiddle example, is it? If the example you provide works what is the problem?

Comment: When I am trying to implement it, new Chart.Tooltip() is not constructable, and throwing errors. @rustyBucketBay

Comment: check with the same chartjs version as in the fiddle you provide to make it work. If you want to update your example to a more recent chartjs version try checking the documentation and if you post any question in that regard put the chartjs version update you target